# ColdFusion 10 Error occurring only in IE9

Tags: coldfusion, internet-explorer-9, coldfusion-10

My customer is encountering the error `The 2 parameter of the Left function, which is now -1, must be a positive integer` after migrating from ColdFusion 8 to ColdFusion 10.  The page performs as expected in Firefox 31 and Chrome 36 on Windows 7.  However, this error occurs in IE9 but not IE7.  Are there different security settings in IE9 that prohibit the processing of the code?

The snippet of code in question is:

```
    <!--- Populate the UserInfo struct --->
<cfloop INDEX="item" LIST="#COOKIE.MYELVIS_USERINFO#" DELIMITERS="&">
    <cfset delim = #FindOneOf("=",item)#>
    <cfif (len(item)-delim)>
        <cfset UserInfo[UCase(left(item,delim-1))] = right(item,len(item)-delim)>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset UserInfo[UCase(left(item,delim-1))] = "">
    </cfif>         
</cfloop>
```

I'm torn to say it's a code error when it works in other browsers, just not IE9.  Any thoughts?  Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the value of that cookie in MSIE 9? You might need to account for something screwy that 9 does to its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps have him clear cookies, he might have a holdover from cf 8 and perhaps the two versions encode differently. It looks like, if this is possible, one of the values doesn't contain a =.

Upon reviewing your code, I think this is what you need.

```
<cfloop INDEX="item" LIST="#COOKIE.MYELVIS_USERINFO#" DELIMITERS="&">
  <cfset delim = #FindOneOf("=",item)#>
  <cfif (delim) and (len(item)-delim)>
    <cfset UserInfo[UCase(left(item,delim-1))] = right(item,len(item)-delim)>
  <cfelse>
    <cfset UserInfo[UCase(item)] = "">
  </cfif>         
</cfloop>
```

Comment: This! Forgot we had the same issue migrating from CF8 to CF9.

Comment: This appears to have worked.  I will have my customer verify, but the error no longer appears for me.  Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: For future reference, what was happening is that when your script found an element that didn't contain an "=", the value of delim was 0. On those rows, left(item,delim-1) was saying 0-1.